# How can I add 10,20,...,50 to each variable in a vector without deleting the current variables?

Tags: r

I would like to handle integers with the length of more than 100k.
Below is the code that works for the small data but I am struggling with handling more than the size of 100k.

test[,2] is the that I want to manage.

It looks like below:

```
[1560502005 1560502065 1560502125 1560502185 1560502245 1560502305 1560502365 ....]
```

The final result that I want to have is:

```
[1560502005 1560502015 1560502025 1560502035 1560502045 1560502055 1560502065 1560502075 ...]
```

which adds 10, 20, ... 50 to each variable of `text[,2]`

The length of the final result would be `6*length(text[,2])`

```
library(jsonlite) #For fromJSON
library(anytime) #For anytime
library(plyr)
```

```
test <- fromJSON('RT_data_this_should_be_used_for_rt_analysis.json')

row_2=nrow(test)
date_data<-data.frame()

#test[,2][1] is a unix time.

for (i in 1:row_2){
  date_data<-rbind.fill(date_data,as.data.frame(rbind(test[,2][i],
                   test[,2][i]+10,
                   test[,2][i]+20,
                   test[,2][i]+30,
                   test[,2][i]+40,
                   test[,2][i]+50))) #Add 10 seconds to match 6 locations
}

head(date_data) #Unix timestamp dataframe

date_data_fixed = data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(date_data)){
  date_data_fixed[i,1] <- anytime(date_data[i,]) #Convert to KRT time
}
head(date_data_fixed)
```

I tried using rbindlist but makes an error like ' Error: Argument 1 must have names'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep` and `seq` to achieve this task.

```
vec <- c(1560502005, 1560502065, 1560502125, 1560502185, 1560502245, 1560502305, 1560502365)

rep(vec, each = 6) + rep(seq(0, 50, 10), times = length(vec))
# [1] 1560502005 1560502015 1560502025 1560502035 1560502045 1560502055 1560502065 1560502075 1560502085
# [10] 1560502095 1560502105 1560502115 1560502125 1560502135 1560502145 1560502155 1560502165 1560502175
# [19] 1560502185 1560502195 1560502205 1560502215 1560502225 1560502235 1560502245 1560502255 1560502265
# [28] 1560502275 1560502285 1560502295 1560502305 1560502315 1560502325 1560502335 1560502345 1560502355
# [37] 1560502365 1560502375 1560502385 1560502395 1560502405 1560502415
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.